# Magento 1.7 show products from 2 categories in block

Tags: php, magento

I wanted to create a block that would display products from 2 (or more) categories. I've tried to do that in several ways but they don't work.

How I tried:

**/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Fulllist.php**
(same as List.php with changed _getProductCollection() function:)

```php
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
        array('finset' => '30'),
        array('finset' => '32'))
    )
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

        return $_productCollection;
}
```

Then, at one of CMS pages i tried to use:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_fulllist" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But that doesn't seem to work, page is clear. Am I missing any part? Or is there an easier way to do that?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Hello check below code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); 

$collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset'=>'30,31')));

$collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

return $collection;
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, when I printed out the query it looks like: [link](http://pastebin.com/tZQGL44X) What I noticed is there is no WHERE clause, is that common in that kind of query? Something apparently doesn't work right. Thank you for help anyway, sir!